# Can a single container have multiple namespaces in Docker?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, dockerfile

Can we create multiple namespaces for a single docker container?

Comment: Namespaces cannot be nested inside one another and each Kubernetes resource can only be in one namespace.

Comment: Could you tell more about your use case? Probably there could an alternative solution for your task.